# Cambiar el color de algunos botones cuando presiono alguno

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer una calculadora y quiero que cuando presione por ejemplo el signo de más, menos, multiplicación, división, el botón presionado se ponga con un color fondo y color de letra distinto a los demás y que si por ejemplo presiono otro signo el signo que cambio de color vuelva a estar como estaba antes y el nuevo presionado cambie.

La solución que hice funciona pero me parece que me queda un código muy largo y no sé si pueda a través de un bucle o algo parecido.

En la función `frestar` se escucha el click de el botón restar y cuando se le da click se le pone el color de fondo y el color de letra y se le cambia al signo de sumar al color con el que estaba antes pero me tocaría hacer lo mismo para cada signo.

```js
//DECLARACION VARIABLES FUNCION OPERACIONES
let sumar= document.getElementById("sumar");
let restar= document.getElementById("restar");
let multipli=document.getElementById("multipli");
let dividir=document.getElementById("dividir");

//
restar.addEventListener("click", frestar);

function frestar(){
    restar.style.color="orange";
    restar.style.backgroundColor="white";
    sumar.style.color="white";
    sumar.style.backgroundColor="orange";
}
```

```css
input[value="÷"], input[value="x"],input[value="-"],input[value="+"],input[value="="]{
    background: rgb(255, 195, 0, 0.9);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="" value="÷"class="buton" id="dividir">
<input type="button" name="" value="x"class="buton" id="multipli">
<input type="button" name="" value="-"class="buton" id="restar">
<input type="button" name="" value="+"class="buton" id="sumar">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías agregar un `listener` a tus 4 botones al igual que hacías con el botón `restar`, a la función le puse el nombre `cambiarColor()`:

```
// A cada botón, le agrego un listener, indicando que al hacer click en ellos, ejecute la función "cambiarColor()"
sumar.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
restar.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
multipli.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
dividir.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
```

Ahora, la función consiste en que restableceremos todos los colores a su estado normal y solo pintaremos al botón quien le hemos dado clic con `this`, ya que con `this` se refiere al botón quien escuchó el evento `click`:

```
function cambiarColor() {
  // Restablecemos los colores a todos los botones...
  sumar.style.color="";
  sumar.style.backgroundColor="";
  restar.style.color="";
  restar.style.backgroundColor="";
  multipli.style.color="";
  multipli.style.backgroundColor="";
  dividir.style.color="";
  dividir.style.backgroundColor="";

  // Y cambiamos el color sólo al botón que se hizo clic.
  this.style.color="orange";
  this.style.backgroundColor="white";
}
```

Código completo:

```js
//DECLARACION VARIABLES DE LOS BOTONES
let sumar = document.getElementById("sumar");
let restar = document.getElementById("restar");
let multipli = document.getElementById("multipli");
let dividir = document.getElementById("dividir");

// A cada botón, le agrego un listener, indicando que al hacer click en ellos, ejecute la función "cambiarColor()"
sumar.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
restar.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
multipli.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);
dividir.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);

function cambiarColor() {
  // Restablecemos los colores a todos los botones...
  sumar.style.color="";
  sumar.style.backgroundColor="";
  restar.style.color="";
  restar.style.backgroundColor="";
  multipli.style.color="";
  multipli.style.backgroundColor="";
  dividir.style.color="";
  dividir.style.backgroundColor="";

  // Y cambiamos el color sólo al botón que se hizo clic.
  this.style.color="orange";
  this.style.backgroundColor="white";
}
```

```css
input[value="÷"], input[value="x"],input[value="-"],input[value="+"],input[value="="]{
  background: rgb(255, 195, 0, 0.9);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="" value="÷"class="buton" id="dividir">
<input type="button" name="" value="x"class="buton" id="multipli">
<input type="button" name="" value="-"class="buton" id="restar">
<input type="button" name="" value="+"class="buton" id="sumar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una propuesta usando el método `querySelectorAll()` con el cual se puede simplificar y mejorar el código que ya tienes.

Básicamente se puede agregar o quitar una clase de `CSS` a través de `JS`, accediendo a los elementos que tengan una clase compartida.

```js
//Obtener todos los botones con clase operator
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

//Recorrer los botones
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  //Agregar el listener para ejecutar la función al hacer click
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    //Ejecutar la funcion resetColor
    resetColor();
    //Agregar la clase operatorClicked solo al botón que recibe el evento
    event.target.classList.add("operatorClicked");
  })
});

//Eliminar la clase operatorClicked de todos los botones para restablecer los colores originales
function resetColor() {  
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.classList.remove("operatorClicked");
  })
};
```

```css
.operator {
  background: rgb(255, 195, 0, 0.9);
  color: white;
}

.operatorClicked {
  background: white;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="" value="÷" class="operator" id="dividir">
<input type="button" name="" value="x" class="operator" id="multipli">
<input type="button" name="" value="-" class="operator" id="restar">
<input type="button" name="" value="+" class="operator" id="sumar">
```